# How to all S3 bucket configuration settings from the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to pull all of the configuration values for an S3 bucket, for example encryption settings, ACL lists, etc from the command line.

Unfortunately, `aws s3api` doesn't seem to have a unified view of configuration, instead you have to query each configuration type individually, for example:

```sh
aws s3api get-bucket-accelerate-configuration --bucket my-bucket >> my-bucket-config
aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket my-bucket >> my-bucket-config
aws s3api get-bucket-cors --bucket my-bucket >> my-bucket-config
# ....and many, many more
```

Is there another API, or method that provides a uniform view of how an S3 bucket is configured from the CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS Config service can provide this type of aggregate configuration information in JSON form.

For example:

```
aws configservice get-resource-config-history \
    --resource-type AWS::S3::Bucket \
    --resource-id mybucket
```